# How to suppress variable substitution in bash heredocs

Tags: bash, syntax, heredoc

Is it possible to create a heredoc that does not become subject to variable expansion?

e.g.

```
cat <<-EOF > somefile.sh
Do not print current value of $1 instead evaluate it later.
EOF
```

**Update**  I am aware of escaping by `\`.  My actual heredoc has many variables in it - and it is error prone and tedious to escape all of them.

Comment: Using `\$var` the variable won't expand

Comment: That's not what I meant. I will update the OP.

Comment: This is a problem for me too. Since functions aren't recognized in pipelines without a load of export and subshell nonsense, I use here docs piped to temp files to define helper functions and it becomes a treasure hunt trying to find out what I've not escaped in the heredoc.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quote the delimiter:

```
cat <<-"EOF"  > somefile.sh
Do not print current value of $1 instead evaluate it later.
EOF
```

This results in:

```
$ cat somefile.sh 
Do not print current value of $1 instead evaluate it later.
```

#### Documentation

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>           <<[-]word
>                   here-document
>           delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  **If
>   any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of
>   quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are
>   not expanded.**  If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence
>   \ is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \,
>   $, and `.
>
> If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing
>   delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be
>   indented in a natural fashion. [Emphasis added.]

Comment: ah! that is what I was looking for.

Comment: This isn't intuitive unfortunately...but I'm glad it exists!

Answer (score 0):

Put backlash before the $ sign

```
$ VAR=XXX
$ cat << END
> dk
> \$VAR
> END
dk
$VAR
```

Comment: I am aware of that.  My heredoc has many of them - too easy to miss one or more.