# Scope inside a heredoc in bash, my $PORT variable is not working

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I can't find anything on the web about this but I can find that I shouldn't use quotes on the `EOT` but in my case I don't so if anyone could help me here that would be awesome..........

This is part of a script to setup new `Debian` installs

**PROBLEM:
I don't get access to $PORT inside the `cat/EOT` `here-document` when it runs.**

```
setUPiptables()
{

    if ! grep -e '-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT' /etc/iptables.up.rules
    then
        cat << EOT >> /etc/iptables.test.rules
        *filter


        IPTABLES-CODE-HERE

        # Allows SSH connections
        # The --dport number is the same as in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport $PORT -j ACCEPT


        IPTABLES-CODE-HERE

        COMMIT
EOT
        sleep 5
        /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.test.rules || exit 127
        sleep 5
        /sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables.up.rules || exit 127
        sleep 3
        printf "#!/bin/bash\n/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules" > /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
        chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
        sleep 6
    fi
}
```

**QUESTION:**

**Can you find/see the problem with `$PORT` in the `cat` `iptables` code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for taking peoples time on this issue it was a beginner mistake that I was reading the filename in the `grep` and not the actual `file`(`/etc/iptables.test.rules`), so I was concatenating the `HERE-DOC` multiple times inside the actual file that `iptables-save` was trying to use with $PORT `duplicates` and off course it fails with all the extra code(gibberish).

Problem solved...... sorry from Iceland.

So I didn't create/code a check if iptables was set and the file `/etc/iptables.test.rules` existed and so I was appending double `iptables` code into a file already containing the code I was writing.

Thank you @CharlesDuffy for your time and advice/guidance

Answer (score 1):

Try to use, as this is duplicate answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code):

`cat <<'EOT' >> /etc/iptables.test.rules`

Comment: Eh? That's not dereferencing the variable at all, that's putting the *literal* text `$PORT` into the heredoc. If the OP wants their heredoc to be nothing *but* literal text, the better way to do it is to change `<<EOF` to `<<'EOF'`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I had the same issue, for me this worked.

Comment: I don't believe what you had was genuinely the same issue. The OP is running `read -r port; PORT=$port` *before* they generate the heredoc, so they want the value they read from the user -- not the variable reference -- to go into the heredoc.

Comment: See the code actually running at https://ideone.com/lYeM97 -- no `\$PORT` is needed to dereference the variable.

Comment: If what the OP wants is to *not* dereference it, by contrast, their question is a duplicate (we have lots of entries for this already in the knowledgebase). See for example [How to cat <<EOF >> a file containing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code), [How to suppress variable substitution in bash heredocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645341/how-to-suppress-variable-substitution-in-bash-heredocs), etc.

Comment: ...and do note the bullet point regarding questions which "*have already been asked and answered many times before*" in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @somethingSomething Let me check and update you soon!