# cat << EOF > ~/.zshrc can not cat original content to file

Tags: shell, cat

i was going to cat a large snippet of shell code to ~/.zshrc file. i was expecting the original content will be showed in the ~/.zshrc file, but what i fond in the file is the result of the content been "rendered". I was expecting the original content in the file.

i was trying to add a single quotation out of the whole content. but that does not work, cause there are both single quotation and double quotation in the content.

below is my snippet of my code:

```
  cat << EOF > ~/.zshrc
zsh_wifi_signal(){
        local output=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I)
        local airport=$(echo $output | grep 'AirPort' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')

        if [ "$airport" = "Off" ]; then
                local color='%F{black}'
                echo -n "%{$color%}Wifi Off"
        else
                local ssid=$(echo $output | grep ' SSID' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')
                local speed=$(echo $output | grep 'lastTxRate' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')
                local color='%F{black}'

                [[ $speed -gt 100 ]] && color='%F{black}'
                [[ $speed -lt 50 ]] && color='%F{red}'

                echo -n "%{$color%}$speed Mbps \uf1eb%{%f%}" # removed char not in my PowerLine font
        fi
}
EOF
```

what in the ~/.zshrc is something like:

```
zsh_wifi_signal(){
    local output= agrCtlRSSI: -53
    agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -92
    agrExtNoise: 0
    state: running
    op mode: station
    lastTxRate: 702
    maxRate: 867
    lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
    link auth: wpa2-psk
    BSSID: 8c:a6:df:18:ac:5f
    SSID: 99cloud_5G
    MCS: 8
    channel: 149,80
    local airport=
    if [ "" = "Off" ]; then
            local color='%F{black}'
            echo -n "%{%}Wifi Off"
    else
            local ssid=
            local speed=
            local color='%F{black}'

            [[  -gt 100 ]] && color='%F{black}'
            [[  -lt 50 ]] && color='%F{red}'

            echo -n "%{%} Mbps \uf1eb%{%f%}" # removed char not in my PowerLine font
    fi
```

which seems to be excuted.

i was expecting something like below in the ~/.zshrc file

```
zsh_wifi_signal(){
        local output=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I)
        local airport=$(echo $output | grep 'AirPort' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')

        if [ "$airport" = "Off" ]; then
                local color='%F{black}'
                echo -n "%{$color%}Wifi Off"
        else
                local ssid=$(echo $output | grep ' SSID' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')
                local speed=$(echo $output | grep 'lastTxRate' | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')
                local color='%F{black}'

                [[ $speed -gt 100 ]] && color='%F{black}'
                [[ $speed -lt 50 ]] && color='%F{red}'

                echo -n "%{$color%}$speed Mbps \uf1eb%{%f%}" # removed char not in my PowerLine font
        fi
}
```

i aslo start a issue in [myrep](https://github.com/albertjone/setup_workspace/issues/6)

Comment: Enclose single-quote around _here-document_ starting part 'EOF' like `cat  > ~/.zshrc <<'EOF'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress variable substitution in bash heredocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645341/how-to-suppress-variable-substitution-in-bash-heredocs)

Comment: And it sounds like you expect it to be appended to you `~/.zshrc` file, so use `cat >> ...`. Good luck.